# Could not build the iOS app Flutter - 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, macos, build

I cannot run or build the iOS app. This always happens with the same error.

- I have already repaired Flutter pub caches.
- Deleted the pod files.
- Removed the iOS folder and tried:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           28.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from /Users/ravindu/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.1/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.m:5:
    /Users/ravindu/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.1/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    In file included from /Users/ravindu/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.m:5:
    /Users/ravindu/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    In file included from /Users/ravindu/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.1/ios/Classes/FLTWebViewFlutterPlugin.m:5:
    /Users/ravindu/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.1/ios/Classes/FLTWebViewFlutterPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    In file included from /Users/ravindu/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.1/ios/Classes/FLTWKProgressionDelegate.m:5:
    /Users/ravindu/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.1/ios/Classes/FLTWKProgressionDelegate.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    In file included from /Users/ravindu/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.1/ios/Classes/FLTWKNavigationDelegate.m:5:
    /Users/ravindu/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.1/ios/Classes/FLTWKNavigationDelegate.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    In file included from /Users/ravindu/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.1/ios/Classes/FLTCookieManager.m:5:
    /Users/ravindu/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.1/ios/Classes/FLTCookieManager.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

Here is the pod file:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    # flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
         if config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'].to_f < 11.0
           config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
         end
      end
  end
end
```

Here is the Pubspec.yaml file:

```
name: fstore
publish_to: "none"
description: Mobile commerce app by Flutter

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 2.8.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  inspireui: 1.0.10

  # Base
  intl: 0.17.0
  crypto: 3.0.1
  path_provider: 2.0.8
  url_launcher: 6.0.17
  localstorage: 4.0.0+1
  http: 0.13.4
  http_auth: 1.0.1
  share: 2.0.4
  wakelock: 0.5.6


  # FIREBASE PACKAGES
  firebase_core: 1.10.5
  firebase_analytics: 9.0.2
  firebase_auth: 3.3.3
  firebase_remote_config: 1.0.2
  firebase_dynamic_links: 4.0.2
  cloud_firestore: 3.1.4

  # STATE MANAGEMENT
  provider: 6.0.1
  get_it: 7.2.0

  # SPLASH SCREEN, ONBOARD
  flare_loading: 3.0.0
  rive: 0.7.33

  # ICON FONTS
  cupertino_icons: 1.0.4

  # WEB TOOLS
  html_unescape: 2.0.0
  webview_flutter: 3.0.0
  webview_flutter_web: 0.1.0
  responsive_builder: 0.4.1
  webview_windows: 0.1.0
  flutter_inappwebview: 5.3.2
  # webview_flutter_wkwebview: ^2.7.1

  # HTML render
  flutter_widget_from_html_core: 0.8.3
  fwfh_text_style: ^2.7.0+1
  fwfh_webview: 0.6.2+1
  fwfh_svg: 0.7.2
  fwfh_cached_network_image: 0.7.0+2
  fwfh_url_launcher: 0.6.1+3
  fwfh_chewie: 0.7.0+1

  # MAP
  google_maps_flutter: 2.1.1
  location: 4.3.0
  maps_launcher: 2.0.1
  geocode: 1.0.1

  # AUTHENTICATION
  the_apple_sign_in: 1.1.1
  flutter_facebook_auth: 3.5.7
  google_sign_in: 5.2.1
  sms_autofill: 2.2.0

  # PUSH NOTIFICATION
  firebase_messaging: 11.2.3
  notification_permissions: 0.6.1
  flutter_local_notifications: 9.1.5
  onesignal_flutter: 3.2.7

  # FILES, IMAGES
  file_picker: 4.2.7
  cached_network_image: 3.2.0
  image: 3.1.0
  transparent_image: 2.0.0
  image_picker: 0.8.4+4
  flutter_native_image: 0.0.6+1
  multi_image_picker2: 5.0.2
  flutter_cache_manager: 3.3.0

  # ADS
  google_mobile_ads: 1.0.1

  # TOOLS
  google_fonts: 2.1.0
  random_string: 2.3.1
  json_annotation: 4.4.0
  timeago: 3.1.0
  universal_platform: 1.0.0+1
  uuid: 3.0.5
  easy_debounce: 2.0.1
  devicelocale: 0.5.0
  collection: 1.15.0
  visibility_detector: 0.2.2
  rate_my_app: 1.1.1+1
  enum_to_string: ^2.0.1
  flutter_linkify: ^5.0.2
  gms_check: ^1.0.0

  # UI
  flutter_spinkit: 5.1.0
  smooth_page_indicator: 1.0.0+2
  animated_text_kit: 4.2.1
  animations: 2.0.2
  flash: 2.0.3
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: 0.4.1
  flutter_swiper_null_safety: 1.0.2
  pull_to_refresh: 2.0.0
  implicitly_animated_reorderable_list: 0.4.2
  rubber: ^1.0.1
  pin_code_fields: 7.3.0
  country_code_picker: 2.0.2
  country_pickers: 2.0.0
  intro_slider: ^3.0.2
  dropdown_search: 2.0.1
  flutter_calendar_carousel: 2.1.0
  currency_text_input_formatter: 2.1.5
  flutter_zoom_drawer: ^2.1.1
  qr_code_scanner: 0.6.1
  paytm_allinonesdk: 1.1.4
  charts_flutter: ^0.12.0

  extended_image:
    git: https://github.com/inspireui/extended_image.git
  razorpay_flutter:
    git: https://github.com/inspireui/razorpay-flutter.git


  ###---- Some extra feature is disable by default -----###
  ### ▶️ Audio Feature
  ### Search "Enable Audio feature" & uncomment to use - https://tppr.me/Z1TX5
  #  audio_manager: ^0.8.1

  ###  Webview Plugin
  ### Search "Enable webview payment plugin" & uncomment to use - https://tppr.me/wlgV1
  # flutter_webview_plugin: 0.4.0

  ###  Facebook Ads
  ### Search "Enable Facebook Ads" & uncomment to use  - https://tppr.me/9Pkf9
  # facebook_audience_network: 1.0.0-nullsafety.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: 1.0.4
  flutter_native_splash: 1.3.2
#  convert_data:
#    path: _dev/convert_data

## Enable to use Flutter Test Driver
#  flutter_driver:
#    sdk: flutter
#  test: 1.16.5
#  dependency_validator: 3.1.0  # pub run dependency_validator

## Enable To run json serializer, run:
## flutter pub run build_runner build --build-filter="lib/models/serializers/*.dart" --delete-conflicting-outputs
## flutter pub run build_runner serve --build-filter="lib/models/serializers/*.dart"
#  build_runner: 2.0.3
#  json_serializable: 4.1.2

#  Run this script to generate the app icon: flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/app_icon.png"

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - lib/config/
    - lib/config/mocks/
    - lib/config/states/
    - lib/config/stories/
    - assets/icons/credit_cards/
    - assets/icons/tabs/
    - assets/icons/payment/
    - assets/icons/logins/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/country/
    - assets/images/favicon/
    - assets/html/
    - google_fonts/

flutter_intl:
  enabled: true
  use_deferred_loading: true
```

I have tried different methods and still same issue.

Answer (score 1):

i have the same issue before a thou days and in mycase the solution was to countinue this steps:

1. Backup Runner folder
2. Delete the ios folder
3. Go to a terminal and execute `flutter create .` in the flutter project folder
4. Paste your Runner folder back into the ios folder
5. `pod deintegrate` in the ios folder
6. `pod install` also in the ios folder
7. `flutter clean` in the flutter project folder
8. `flutter pub get`
9. `flutter run`

Please note that if you use firebase you need to re-insert the GoogleService-Info.plist file

Hope it helps!